# How was it 2020 so soon after July 2019?

Tags: continuity, outer-banks

In Season 1 Episode 4 of *[Outer Banks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_Banks_(TV_series))* we are shown the coroner's report of the murders being investigated, which reveals the date to be July 19th, 2019:

[image: Screenshot of clip showing coroner's report]

Over the course of the first season, it seems pretty clear that not much time elapses. Everything seems to happen in a manner of days, and it is most certainly still summer at the end of the first season when John B and Sarah disappear.

Season 2 begins with a scene of John B's friends thinking he is dead and carving his name and lifespan into a tree. The year of death that they put is 2020:

[image: Screenshot of clip showing tree carving with the year as 2020]

How is this possible? By all counts, John B would have died in July, perhaps at the latest August, 2019.

In fact, later in the same episode it seems to be the first day of school, so depending on local school scheduling this would presumably be around the beginning of September:

[image: Screenshot of clip showing the welcome back sign at school]